# Geting results from database one by one

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm writing small program that is querying for results from database (single table). I'm using python 3.3, sqlalchemy and postgres database.

```
result = db_session.query(Data).all()
progress = 0
for row in result:
    update_progress_bar(progress, len(result))
    do_something_with_data(row)
    progress += 1
```

Variable 'result' will contain few thousands rows, and processing of data is taking some time. This is why I introduced simple progress bar to give idea how mutch time it will take. 
The problem is, that 30% of the total time is queering the database (first line). So when I start program I get big delay before my progress bar start moving. In addition I don't need to keep all results in memory. I can process them separately.

Is there any way to modify above program to get rows one by one until all rows are received, without loading everything into memory? In addition I want to monitor progress of querying and processing the data.

Comment: Thanks to EOL sugestion, I have a look into 'streaming results'. To get it to work, I have to run query with ".execution_options(stream_results = True)". I also find out that my database adapter (pypostgresql) is not supporting streaming. The only one that is capable to do it, is psycop2. Lucky for me, new psycop2 2.5 supports now python 3.3 :) I will test and share experience :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just loop over the query *without* calling `.all()`, *and* call [`.yield_per()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per) to set a batch size:

```
for row in db_session.query(Data).yield_per(10):
    do_something_with_data(row)
```

`.all()` indeed turns the whole result set into a list *first*, causing a delay if the resultset is large. Iterating over the query directly after setting `.yield_per()` instead fetches results as needed, *provided the database API supports it*.

If you wanted to know up-front how many rows will be returned, call `.count()` first:

```
result = db_session.query(Data)
count = result.count()

for row in result.yield_per(10):
    update_progress_bar(progress, count)
    do_something_with_data(row)
    progress += 1
```

`.count()` asks the *database* to gives us an item count for us first.

Your database could *still* be pre-caching the result rows, leading to a start-up delay, even when using `.yield_per()`. In that case you'll need to use a [windowed query](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/WindowedRangeQuery) to break up your query into blocks based on the range of values in *one* of the columns. Wether or not this will work depends on your exact table layout.

Comment: Do you have a reference on the iterator fetching results as needed? If I remember correctly, not many DBAPIs support streaming, and Sqlite3 in particular fetches all the rows fist.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get delay before program get to the main loop. I forget to mention, I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Marek: The database *itself* can easily require some startup time before it can start serving data. It could also be that the database API itself doesn't support streaming. Using `.all()` *guarantees* you load everything into memory first, iterating over the query at least gives the underlying database API the *chance* to give you results in batches.

Comment: @Marek: I forgot to add the `.yield_all()` call needed to switch to streaming modus. Psycopg2 should support operating in this mode.

Comment: @Martijn: Please see my comment to my question.

Comment: @Marek: `.yield_per()` sets `execution_options` for you.

Comment: After updating to psycopg2 2.5, I finally manage to get this to work. I used .yield_all() method. Thanks for help. I learn something new :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: One can directly do `for row in query.yield_by(…):` instead of adding an intermediate step.

Comment: @EOL: For some reason I thought the `.per_yield()` method did *not* chain; I had missed the `@_generative` decorator on that method in the source code.